# profiling and personalisation using microservice

Tags: web8, odata, microservices, personalization, profiling

Is it possible to use web8 microservice (oData) to achieve profiling and personalisation? if yes where I can find documentation for the same?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the (legacy) Personalization & Profiling functionality is not exposed through SDL Web 8 CIL APIs, but only in the (deprecated) in-process APIs.

Note that Experience Optimization (and to some extent Context Expressions) functionality is considered the successor of Personalization & Profiling functionality.  But, admittedly, neither covers all of P&P.

Can you elaborate on where you need P&P for?

Comment: We want to Personalizing content in Android or IOS Apps.

Comment: Can you give a concrete  example of "Personalizing content" ?

Comment: If user is navigating to the same type of product information or if user belongs to specific region, we want to show targeted content.

Comment: I think that Experience Optimization is suitable for this kind of requirements.

Comment: When checked with SDL they don't have any documentation related to Smart target usage in Mobile Apps , looks like no one used this scenario.